# How to reloadData in class which implements UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols?(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I understand that if I was using a TableViewController class I could use:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Although, this doesn't work with a class that conforms to certain tableView protocols.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same way (although view controllers that are not `UITableViewController`s will not have a `tableView` property unless you define it and connect it yourself.